# Terminal prompt changed

Tags: terminal, iterm

[image]

So, I was trying to add Laravel to my list of executable commands and, somehow, I fudged up my iTerm 2 (and regular Terminal) and now they both appear like this.

```
MacBook-Pro%
```

That just looks ugly. How do I change back to what it once was? With the Git indicator, folder name, colors, etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
nano .bash_profile
```

Then add:

```
export PS1=" "
```

Between those quotation marks, add any of the following between the quotation marks of export PS1=" ":

```
\d – Current date
\t – Current time
\h – Host name
\# – Command number
\u – User name
\W – Current working directory (ie: Desktop/)
\w – Current working directory with full path (ie: /Users/Admin/Desktop/)
```

Also you can customize the look and feel of terminal, or restore the defaults in Terminal > Preferences > Profiles

http://osxdaily.com/2006/12/11/how-to-customize-your-terminal-prompt/